# Fluid volume disappears inside of a moving object?

Tags: animation, keyframes, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I've noticed that with the flip fluids addon and the built-in fluid simulator in blender, if you have fluid inside of a moving obstacle/effector, that fluid volume will eventually disappear over the course of the animation when the obstacle/effector is moving. And it seems this is a well-known problem that's been around for a while and is still not fixed. I've tried increasing resolution, timesteps, but nothing works.

How I have my scene is with a wine glass being filled with fluid, before being twirled around to make the fluid fly out of the top, with time keyframing to slow it down and speed it up. Is there any other way to create an animation like this, or work around this problem?